# Properties of the orbit $Abx_0$ when $b$ is upper or lower triangular but not diagonal

Tags: lie-groups, ds.dynamical-systems, homogeneous-spaces

Let $G=\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)$ and $\Gamma = \text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$. The homogeneous space is identified with the space of unimodular lattices, denoted $X_d$. Let $A$ denote the subgroup of $G$ consisting of all diagonal matrices of positive entries (of course, the determinant has to be one).

Let $x_0$ be a point in $X_d$ with compact $A$-orbit. Namely $Ax_0$ is compact

Let $b$ be an upper or lower triangular, but not diagonal, matrix in $G$. I have two speculations about the orbit $Abx_0$:

(1) $Abx_0$ is not compact.

(2) $\overline{Abx_0}$ contains a compact orbit of $A$, say some $Ay$ (compact in $X_d$).

How do we prove these two properties rigorously?

---

The reason I am asking about these two properties is that in the case when $d=3$, we could use the corollary 1.4 here from the paper of Lindenstrauss and Weiss 2001 [https://www.math.bgu.ac.il/~barakw/papers/lit.pdf#page=2#](https://www.math.bgu.ac.il/%7Ebarakw/papers/lit.pdf#page=2#)
to conclude that $Abx_0$ is actually dense in $X_3$. Also see https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.4289.pdf#page=8# (bottom of the paper), where this is actually used without proof.